# How to get a list of Field Set names in Apex

Tags: apex, map, sobject, schema, fieldsets

I need to create combobox with Field Set names. I know how to get fields for any Field Set, but how to get a list of all Field Set names.

Map<String, Schema.FieldSet> canMap = Schema.SObjectType.Candidate__c.fieldSets.getMap();

Maybe there are methods like getValue or getNames, or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`canMap` in your example code does contain the fieldset names. They're the keys of the map, so you can retrieve them by using the `keySet()` method from the Map class.

`Set<String> fieldSetNames =  canMap.keySet();`

I'm not 100% certain if that gets you the (API) name, or the label of the fieldset. If you find that you need the other fieldset identifier, then the [Fieldset class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_fieldsets_describe.htm) has methods to get what you need (this would involve a loop).

Comment: Thank you! It works)